# Issues for launch one-shot task in Cloud Foundry v2

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-task

Currently I'm just trying to use the spring cloud task feature in pivotal public cloud with my account, the api version is 2.63. I just copy the [only complete sample code from the spring cloud task document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-developing-first-task), build and package locally and push to the cloud foundry, and specify "no-route: true" and "health-check-type: none" in manifest.yml. But it seems no use, the log shows error info "Process has crashed with type: web" after successfully run the sample and destroy the container. So I wonder why cloud foundry think my applications is a web based application, because judging from the dependency, I only use the spring-cloud-task-core and spring-boot-starter. Why it still perform health check even I've set it to avoid this kinds of check?

Comment: Can you provide your `manifest.yml` please?

Comment: I'll later post the manifest, actually it's very simple,only no-route and health-check-type are special.

Comment: I think I may have a misunderstanding of the property health-check-type. It has only effects when app is started. Currently my app can successfully run. Later I push a native hello world app, it can also run. The crash occurred after the app finished running and container destroyed, and Cloud Foundry continuously restart it,which is not I want, just like in V3 it has already support the task feature.So the health-check-type set to none also can't prevent this check, right?

Comment: I think if the process terminates, CF will try and bring it back to life. Are you able to use this for tasks? https://github.com/cloudfoundry/v3-cli-plugin

Comment: Previously I just judging from literal of health-check-type and think it will prevent Cloud Foundry to restart app when the app finished. V3 hasn't in release status so currently I can't use it in my project.

Comment: Have you tried? The V3 endpoints should be in your version of CF.

Comment: Yes, V3 support the task feature, but our project deployed a version of V2, so still could not use V3.

Comment: Have you tried it out? If you're on version 2.63 of the API, then you must be on v245 of cf-release, which definitely has the Cloud Controller code with v3 functionality in it.

Comment: Oh, really? I heard the fact from other colleague that V3 support one-off app, and I saw our current version is 2.61, this is our product environment. Thanks a lot. Could you tell me from which api version the task feature is supported? Does 2.61 also support? I'll have a try.

Comment: @EngineerBetter, I also ran into this issue recently. I am having a look at the link you provided (v3-cli-plugin). Can you please advise on how spring cloud task relates to CF/PCF tasks?

Answer (score 0):

The health-check-type property has effects only for worker application to ensure not crash during application start and run in Diego container. But when the application finished and container destroyed, this property can't prevent Diego to take it as a crash issue and restart it. Only Cloud Foundry V3 start to support the feature of Task.